# Apple iPhone 5 support moiblefirst application

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, iphone-5

I have Iphone 5 can I run mobilefirst integrated cordova , ionic hybrid application in my device .

what is the minimum requirement  to run mobilefirst with cordova , ionic hybrid application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system requirements for MobileFirst Platform Foundation V7.1 are listed [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/r_supported_operating_systems_an.html).  There is also a tech note on using MobileFirst Platform Foundation with Ionic [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1502_maynard/1502_maynard.html).

For both components (MobileFirst Platform Foundation and Ionic), the requirement is that the iOS device be running iOS 6 or later.

Comment: but here everything is IOS and Andorid . Where is Windows what is the requirement for windows apps .

Comment: Your original question only asked about iPhone - but, the supported Windows environments are listed in the system requirements document (linked above) as well.  For example, see:  http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88&osPlatform=Mobile%20OS

Comment: yea original question only asked about iPhone . thank you .